# How do I include header file

Tags: c++

I have a packet class and a packetfactory class.

In packet factory class it includes packet.h file and in packet class it includes packetfacotry.h file.

Then I am getting an error "packet does not name a type " in packetfactory.h file.

How do I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us a stripped-down version of your files if you can. I don't know much c++ but you might need a forward class declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 ways :

First, you can `#include "packet.h"` in packetfacotry and `#include "packetfacotry.h"`. DO NOT forget to protect your headers.

Second, if you have an circular inclusion juste add `class packet;` in your "packetfacotry.h. file or vice versa.
It declares symbols for preprocessor.

So ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like very common circular dependency problem, you may search circular dependency and pImpl, there are very good answers.

Answer (score 0):

If packetfactory.h refers to a packet class that's described in packet.h, then you need to have packetfactory.h itself include packet.h early on. Headers can and often do include other headers.

Unfortunately this is just a guess as to what's going on, since you don't provide any source code or an exact error. I'm assuming that this is the problem however because mention that the error line is in the header, not the implementation file.